# How do I replace an HTML String with another one?

Tags: jquery

I need to replace `<p>&nbsp;</p>` with `<p class="spacer">&nbsp;</p>`

I tried this option using **replaceAll** but it doesn't work.

```
$('<p class="spacer">&nbsp;</p>').replaceAll( "<p>&nbsp;</p>" );
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Aren't you just adding the spacer class to the paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you are doing is adding a class so loop over and find the elements that match and add the class.

```js
$("p").filter(function() {
  return this.innerHTML === "&nbsp;"
}).addClass("spacer");
```

```css
.spacer {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>A</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>A</p>
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Nice hat!

Answer (score 1):

try `.replaceWith()` The .replaceWith() method removes content from the DOM and inserts new content in its place with a single call. Consider this DOM structure:

```
$( ".spacer" ).replaceWith( "<p>&nbsp;</p>" );
```

```js
$( ".spacer" ).replaceWith( "<p>test&nbsp;test</p>" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p class="spacer">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: I tried your code but it did not work in my situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you are trying to replace HTML more than just add a class attribute. If so, this also works as I tested it in my browser. You would have jQuery add the class attribute like this:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('p').attr('class','spacer');
        });
```

However this would target ALL P tags, so if this is the first one, you can use

```
        $(document).first().ready(function(){
            $('p').attr('class','spacer');
        });
```

Bruce